# Can not download wordpress themes locally

Tags: wordpress, curl, proxy, themes

I have installed wordpress in my xampp server.
everything looks great.
I am using proxy so i have added below snippet in wp_config.php to use proxies.

```
/* Configure proxy Server */
define('WP_PROXY_HOST', '192.56.14.2');
define('WP_PROXY_PORT', '5656');
define('WP_PROXY_USERNAME', 'xxxx');
define('WP_PROXY_PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
```

when i try to INSTALL any theme. It shows following Error.

- Installation failed: Download failed. cURL error 56: Proxy CONNECT aborted [Like this_Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n00Gd.png)

I couldn't find much on this.Any help please?

Comment: Could it be that you're trying to connect to a SOCKS proxy? If you check the function `request()` in `wp-includes/class-wp-http-curl`, it's always setting `CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE` to `CURLPROXY_HTTP`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?